# How can I insert a blob and timestamp into a table in Oracle using Perl?

Tags: sql, oracle, perl, dbi

I have an Oracle table as shown below.
I need to insert a record in this table using perl.
**The data to be inserted includes varchar, number, blob, and timestamp.**
I do not insert attr1 as it defaults to zero.
**Also, is there a way to get the number of rows inserted?**

I came up with some code, but it's incomplete. I'm looking for help on how to code it and will appreciate any help especially since I'm a complete newbie to perl.

```
table
    attr1 INT DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    attr2 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    attr3 NUMBER NOT NULL,
    attr4 BLOB NOT NULL,
    attr5 TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT table_pk PRIMARY KEY (attr1, attr2)
```

```
use DBD::Oracle qw(:ora_types);

sub blob_and_other_data {
    my $attr2 = shift; # varchar data looks like '38573985-45643756283'
    my $attr3 = shift; # number data looks like '-9394857384' 
    my $attr4 = shift; # blob data
    my $attr5 = shift; # timestamp data looks like '03-Jun-21 4:38:34 pm'
    my $sql_statement = "insert into table (attr2, attr3, attr4, attr5) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";

    my $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql_statement);

    $sth->bind_param(1, $attr2);
    $sth->bind_param(2, $attr3, { ora_type => ? }); # not even sure if this is needed
    $sth->bind_param(3, $attr4, { ora_type => ORA_BLOB });
    $sth->bind_param(4, $attr5, { ora_type => ? }); # not even sure if this is needed

    $sth->execute();
}
```

Comment: I am not familiar with Oracle, but it seems the `TIMESTAMP` data type is described [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html#:~:text=The%20TIMESTAMP%20data%20type%20is,microseconds%20(6%20digits)%20precision.) and the `BLOB` data type is described [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/blob.html#:~:text=A%20BLOB%20is%20a%20binary,TEXT%20%2C%20MEDIUMTEXT%20%2C%20and%20LONGTEXT%20.). So you are asking how to convert from Perl custom format to these types?

Answer (score 1):

For timestamp I use this one, which is in line with [OTHER DATA TYPES](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBD::Oracle#OTHER-DATA-TYPES):

```
my $sql_statement = "insert into table (attr5) VALUES (TO_TIMESTAMP(? ,'DD-Mon-RR HH:MI:SS AM', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=AMERICAN'))";
my $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql_statement);
$sth->bind_param(1, $attr5);
$sth->execute();
```

For LOB's I found [Binding for Updates and Inserts for CLOBs and BLOBs](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBD::Oracle#Binding-for-Updates-and-Inserts-for-CLOBs-and-BLOBs), but I never used it.

```
my $in_clob = "<document>\n";
$in_clob .= "  <value>$_</value>\n" for 1 .. 10_000;
$in_clob .= "</document>\n";
my $in_blob ="0101" for 1 .. 10_000;
 
$SQL='insert into test_lob3@tpgtest (id,clob1,clob2, blob1,blob2) values(?,?,?,?,?)';
$sth=$dbh->prepare($SQL );
$sth->bind_param(1,3);
$sth->bind_param(2,$in_clob,{ora_type=>SQLT_CHR});
$sth->bind_param(3,$in_clob,{ora_type=>SQLT_CHR});
$sth->bind_param(4,$in_blob,{ora_type=>SQLT_BIN});
$sth->bind_param(5,$in_blob,{ora_type=>SQLT_BIN});
$sth->execute();
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Let me give this a try Wernfried.

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me:

```
eval{blob_and_other_data($attr2, $attr3, $attr4, $attr5)};

sub blob_and_other_data {
    my $attr2 = shift;
    my $attr3 = shift;
    my $attr4 = shift;
    my $attr5 = shift;
    my $sql_statement = "insert into table (attr2, attr3, attr4, attr5) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
    
    my $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql_statement);

    $sth->bind_param(1, $attr2);
    $sth->bind_param(2, $attr3);
    $sth->bind_param(3, $attr4, { ora_type => ORA_BLOB } );
    $sth->bind_param(4, $attr5);

    $sth->execute();
}
```